# How to loop an object around another

Tags: modeling

So I am a complete beginner in blender and I am trying to create a boxing ring and I am having an issue with getting the strap to loop around the cylinder. I have tried beveling and extruding but it always has like a pointy edge and it`s not completely smooth. I want it to look like these photos.

https://www.google.com/search?q=boxing%20ring&tbm=isch&hl=en&tbs=rimg:CS7iAJKq5oVeYeguU1F24TGi&sa=X&ved=0CB0QuIIBahcKEwjokZWIg9X1AhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQCA&biw=1903&bih=975#imgrc=RKOFxD_n5g0ZjM

https://www.google.com/search?q=boxing%20ring&tbm=isch&hl=en&tbs=rimg:CbjVBGBdvokSYTbxtBzCfeNasgIA&sa=X&ved=0CBsQuIIBahcKEwj4sNTGnNX1AhUAAAAAHQAAAAAQLA&biw=1903&bih=975#imgrc=UL5wuYoUXA33HM

Comment: Hi and welcome! You have linked to several images. Please [edit] your question, and use the built in tools to make the images a part of the question so that users do not need to follow many external links to find information. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

you could use geometry nodes for this, it is fully procedural and you can adjust any parameter any time.

Node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]